# Align button beside callout

Tags: html, css

how can I align a button beside a callout like the one shown on picture?

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
.calloutS2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 7%;
}

.buttonOkS2 {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  float: right;
}

.buttonObserve {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="calloutS2" id="callOutStep2"><b><u><font size="5">Step 2:</font></u></b>
  <p class="ps1" id="ps2">
    <font size="4">Length of unknown side =<br>Total length of unknown sides ÷ 2</font>
    <button class="buttonOkS2" id="buttonOkS2"></button>
  </p>
</div>
<div><button class="buttonObserve" id="buttonObserve"></button></div>
```

Comment: add flex for p tag.. its working fine e.x p {display:flex;}

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your whole content inside of a `div` and then display it as `flex`, this will align your two boxes.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
#callOutStep2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="calloutS2" id="callOutStep2"><b><u><font size="5">Step 2:</font></u></b>
  <p class="ps1" id="ps2"><font size="4">Length of unknown side =<br>Total length of unknown sides ÷ 2</font>
    <button class="buttonOkS2" id="buttonOkS2">OK</button>
  </p>
</div>
<div><button class="buttonObserve" id="buttonObserve">Let's Observe</button></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to do this with flex-box:

```css
.callout {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
  background:#eee;
}

.calloutS2 {
  background:#ccffcc;
  border:1px solid green;
  font-size:1em;
  display:flex;
  margin:3px 10px 3px 0;
}
.calloutS2 h1 {
  font-size:1.5em; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;
  margin-top:0;
  
}


.text-wrapper {
  padding:3px;
}
.button-wrapper {
  align-self:flex-end;
  padding:3px;
}
.buttonOkS2 {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:4px;
}

.buttonObserve {
  background:yellow;
  color:black;
  width:110px;
  height:70px;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border:4px double black;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout">
  <div class="calloutS2" id="callOutStep2">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
    <h1>Step 2:</h1>
    Length of unknown side =<br>Total length of unknown sides ÷ 2
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="buttonOkS2" id="buttonOkS2">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <button class="buttonObserve" id="buttonObserve">Let's Observe</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the excellent [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on css-tricks.com for help with understanding flex-box.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could easily achieve this with flex. Also, in my opinion float is never an elegant way of aligning elements.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#callout {
  height: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.callout-button {
  background-color: #FFFF66;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 40px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="callout">Callout content</div>
  <button class="callout-button">Let's Observe</button>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hugopires/pen/eYYWxVR)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .main {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    #callOutStep2 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      background-color: #cfc;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .calloutS2 {
      left: 7%;
      color: #009900;
    }
    
    .buttonOkS2 {
      vertical-align: text-top;
      float: right;
      background-color: #970403;
      padding: 5px;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 35px;
      margin: 0 0 0 15px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .buttonObserve {
      float: right;
      background-color: #ff6;
      padding: 7px;
      outline: none;
      border: 1px solid #000 !important;
      box-shadow: none;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
      width: 102px;
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
      line-height: normal;
    }
    
    [type=button]:not(:disabled),
    [type=reset]:not(:disabled),
    [type=submit]:not(:disabled),
    button:not(:disabled) {
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="calloutS2" id="callOutStep2"><b><u><font size="5">Step 2:</font></u></b>
        <p class="ps1" id="ps2">
          <font size="4">Length of unknown side =<br>Total length of unknown sides ÷ 2</font>
          <button class="buttonOkS2" id="buttonOkS2">ok</button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="buttonObserve" id="buttonObserve">Let's observe!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```